# Memory leak while copy fbo image

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks

As you can see in the Image I've a memory leak while copying the fbo to a `QImage`. Anyone out there who knows a possible solution?

[image]

```
QOpenGLFramebufferObject *fbo;

void GLANN::render(){

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Set random seed
        //program.setUniformValue("seedX", ((float)qrand()/RAND_MAX));
        //program.setUniformValue("seedY", ((float)qrand()/RAND_MAX));

        //Set number of alredy rendered passes
        //program.setUniformValue("numRenderPass",mRenderPasses);

        //Set program to fbo render mode
        program.setUniformValue("fbo",true);

        //Bind last rendered Image
        //pixelsRenderedImage = bindTexture(*renderedImage);

        //Load Identity
        //glLoadIdentity();

        //Move to rendering point
        //glTranslatef( -1.0, -1.0, 0.0f );

        // Draw geometry
        // Tell OpenGL which VBOs to use

         // Render to our framebuffer
         fbo->bind();
         glViewport(0,0,TexWidth,TexHeight);

         // Tell OpenGL which VBOs to use
         glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId0);
         glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId1);

         // Offset for position
         int offset = 0;

         // Tell OpenGL programmable pipeline how to locate vertex position data
         int vertexLocation = program.attributeLocation("a_position");
         program.enableAttributeArray(vertexLocation);
         glVertexAttribPointer(vertexLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), (const void *)offset);

         // Offset for texture coordinate
         offset += sizeof(QVector3D);

         // Tell OpenGL programmable pipeline how to locate vertex texture coordinate data
         int texcoordLocation = program.attributeLocation("a_texcoord");
         program.enableAttributeArray(texcoordLocation);
         glVertexAttribPointer(texcoordLocation, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), (const void *)offset);

         //glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

         glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
         glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, pixelsRenderedImage);

         // Draw cube geometry using indices from VBO 1
         glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 5, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

//         qDebug() << glGetError() << "Line 183";

         fbo->release();

     renderedImage.~QImage();
     renderedImage = QImage();
     renderedImage = fbo->toImage().copy();
     pixelsRenderedImage = QGLWidget::bindTexture(renderedImage);
     //Set Program to screen frendering
     program.setUniformValue("fbo",false);
     //Set Viewport back to default
     glViewport(0,0,width,height);
     //Render To Screen
     //glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
     glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
     glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, pixelsRenderedImage);

     // Draw quad geometry using indices from VBO 1
     glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 5, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);


}
```

Comment: Could you please add the entire method? That type is `fbo`?

Comment: I don't think it has to do something with the problem, but you can remove the line `renderedImage.~QImage();` since old data will be released by the assignment operator in the line below it. And `renderedImage = QImage();` is also useless because you overwrite it in the next line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the bug in the part of "bindTexture".

Added:

```
 glDeleteTextures(1,&pixelsRenderedImage);
```

solved the problem.